# json inside a json object not handling properly

Tags: javascript, json

i'm putting a JSON object withing a JSon object with adding another value but when i print it it gives [Object Object]. not giving the values in json format. code is following.

```
var Json1 = {"name":"OMAR"};
var data=null;
var json2 = {"ID":12345 ,data:Json1 };
```

I'm confused where i'm doing wrong. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the post in which you print it.

Comment: sorry it writing mistake , its var json2{"ID":12345 , data:Json1}; but i'm getting [object Object] while printing json2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some error in your code:

1.You need not to define a variable to add an object inside another object.

```
var data = null; // you need not to define it
var json2 = {
    "ID": 12345,
    data = json1
};
```

2.Replace

```
var json2 = {
    "ID": 12345,
    data = json1
}; // wrong
```

with

```
var json2 = {
    "ID": 12345,
    "data": Json1 
}; // right
```

Correct Code:

```
var Json1 = {
    "name": "OMAR"
};
var json2 = {
    "ID": 12345,
    "data": Json1 
};
```

In Order to alert its value:

Try This: `JSON.stringify(json2);`

Answer (score 1):

Your third line currently has a syntax error because a `:` is expected where the `=` is, and also JavaScript is case sensitive so you need a capital J in `Json1` to match the variable on the first line (or change that variable to a lowercase j):

```
var json2 = {"ID":12345, data : Json1 };
```

If you did that you'd find that `json2.data.name` returned `"OMAR"`.

Also, the `data` variable and `data` as a property of the second object are not the same thing.

Also, terminology nitpick: [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

For more details about working with JavaScript objects, MDN has an article titled, conveniently, ["Working with objects"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

Two typo's in your code:

```
var Json1 = {"name":"OMAR"};
var data=null;
var json2 = {"ID":12345 ,data:Json1 };
//                           ^ = should be :
//                            ^ json1 should be Json1
```

Now if you require a value from `json2.data`, retrieve it like this:

```
console.log(json2.data.name); //=> "OMAR"
```

Furthermore, your code can be rewritten as:

```
var json2 = { "ID":12345 ,data:{"name":"OMAR"} };
```